# Why do I get 404 error when trying to send specific POST requests to Nest JS server?

Tags: angular, http, nestjs

I am working on a simple fullstack project with CRUD capabilities. When I send DELETE and PATCH requests from the Angular frontend to the Nest JS server I am getting a 404 not found error in the browser. I have verified that my GET requests and one of my POST requests (the one for creating new "dishes") are working fine and I have checked the URL and routing for typos but it looks fine. I have ensured that I ran npm run start:dev to update the dist folder and the route explorer in the terminal says that it is successfully mapping all routes. I have also ensured that the problem is not due to CORS. I am not sure why I am getting these 404 errors when I try to DELETE or PATCH/UPDATE a "dish" that is stored in the Postgresql database?

**dishes.service.ts (Angular)**

```
 @Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
 })
 export class DishesService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getDishes(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/dishes');
  }

  query(cuisine: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/dishes/query/${cuisine}`);
  }

  postDish(dish: Dish) {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/dishes', dish).subscribe(data =>{
    });
  }

//this causes 404 error
  updateDish(dish: Dish) {
    return this.http.post(`http://localhost:3000/dishes/update/${dish.id}`, dish);
  } 

//this causes 404 error
  deleteDish(dish: Dish) {
    return this.http.post(`http://localhost:3000/dishes/delete/${dish.id}`, null);
  }

}
```

**dishes.controller.ts (NestJS)**

```
export class DishesController {

    constructor(private readonly dishesService: DishesService) {}

    @Post()
    async create(@Body() dish: Dish): Promise<Dishes[]> {
        return this.dishesService.create(dish);
    }

    @Get()
    async findAll(): Promise<Dishes[]> {
        return this.dishesService.findAll();
    }

    @Get('query/:cuisine')
    async query(@Param('cuisine') cuisine: string): Promise<any> {
        return this.dishesService.query(cuisine);
    }

//this causes 404 error
    @Patch('update/:id')
    async update(@Param('id') id: number, @Body() dish: Dish): Promise<any> {
        dish.id = id
        return this.dishesService.update(dish);
    }

//this causes 404 error
    @Delete('delete/:id')
    async delete(@Param('id') id: number): Promise<any> {
        return this.dishesService.delete(id);
    }

}
```

**dishes.service.ts (NestJS)**

```
export class DishesService {

    constructor(@InjectRepository(Dishes)
        private readonly dishesRepository: Repository<Dishes>
    ) {}

    async create(dish: Dish): Promise<any> {
        return await this.dishesRepository.save(dish);
    }

    async findAll(): Promise<Dishes[]> {
        return this.dishesRepository.find();
    }

    async query(cuisine: string): Promise<Dishes[]> {
        return this.dishesRepository.find({ where: { cuisine: cuisine } });
    }

//this causes 404 error
    async update(dish: Dish): Promise<UpdateResult> {
        return await this.dishesRepository.update(dish.id, dish);
    }

//this causes 404 error
    async delete(id: number): Promise<any> {
        return this.dishesRepository.delete(id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your angular service, you're only calling `post` methods. The update and delete use the HTTP verbs `patch` and `delete` respectively.

```js
//this causes 404 error
  deleteDish(dish: Dish) {
    return this.http.post(`http://localhost:3000/dishes/delete/${dish.id}`, null);
  }
```

Notice the `this.http.post`? It's a POST request where this should be `this.http.delete`. That's the kind of endpoint you set up, right?

```js
//this causes 404 error
    @Delete('delete/:id')
    async delete(@Param('id') id: number): Promise<any> {
        return this.dishesService.delete(id);
    }
```